# How to make multiline textField in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, textview, uitextfield, textfield

I have around 25 words, which I need to copy into clipboard (25 different for each category). At first I've made a textView, but  it is not possible to copy it into clipboard. So I used a textField, but it doesnt look good, because it has only one line and it doesnt show all of the words.

Is there any way I can make textField multiline or any way to copy content of textView?

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: `UITextField` support only one line, but You can copy from an `UITextView`. What is your error with this?

Comment: You can copy textview text into clipboard